# How to create a header that can be added into files flask

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am wondering how to create a jinja2 template that would allow my to put my header into a variable where I can extend the base file and then call upon the header in my child file.

**Currently my code for the parent is:**

```
{% block head %}
<div class="wrapper col2">
    <div id="topbar">
    <div id="topnav">
      <ul>

          <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="sign-up">Sign in/up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Admin console</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/WelcomeAdmin/">Console</a></li>
            <li><a href="staffman">Staff Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="AlertConsole">ALERTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="shootersign">Sign up Shooters</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li ><a href="contact-us">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="/Logout">logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br class="clear" />
  </div>
        <hr>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul>
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**My child template is:**

```
{% extends "Header.html" %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
<h1>CREATE SHOOT</h1>

<form action="" method="post" name="form">
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      <p>
          <h2>Name of shoot:</h2>
          {{ form.nameofshoot(size=40) }}<br>
    <h2>Number of days in shoot:</h2>
            {{ form.day}}
      <p><input type="submit" value="Create Shoot"></p>
  </form>
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another approach I can take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is remove from your child template the lines `{% block head %}{% endblock %}`

Because in your child template you call `{% extends "Header.html" %}`, all of the content declared in Header.html (no matter what blocks it is in) will automatically be included. That's the job of extends.

By adding the `{% block head %}{% endblock %}` in your child template, what you have effectively said is "take everything from Header.html, but override everything in the 'head' block with what I specify in my child template". Then, because there is nothing in the block defined in your child template, you are replacing the content defined in your Header.html file with nothing.

You want to use the `{% block blockname %}` notation to specify what you want to change in the child template, not what you want to keep the same.

[This page on inheritence](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#template-inheritance) is the relevant section of the Jinja documentation, and provides a nice example.

Comment: Now my html that was defined is not working it is just like an image but not an image

Comment: I'm sorry, your comment doesn't make sense to me. "Just like an image but not an image"? Is this now a different question?

Comment: No it is the same question but after updating the code my form now no longer acts as a form but instead as similar to an image as in it is not interactive. The HTML I am talking about is under the **child template**

Comment: I suppose what I'm asking is, does the html for the parent show up? Did my answer help you? In that case, then that problem has been fixed, and the form not working is possibly a new issue which might require a new question.

Comment: Yes it displays correctly just does not function correctly